# nvidia-settings lost after reboot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 13.10

I have a fresh ubuntu 13.10 install and a dual-monitor setup. I can't get the setup working propely because the monitor settings get reverted every time I reboot.

How do I fix this?

Note that I get the initial settings when I start nvidia-settings after a logout/reboot.

Answer (score 7):

Okay I got it working: You have to change the display settings in `system settings -> display` as well.

Now everything works like a charm!

Comment: what you did pls elaborate

Comment: Very simple and made the trick. Thanks brother!

Answer (score 3):

The only solution for me was `dconf-editor`, and search for `xrandr` using `Ctrl-F`.

Disable the following keys:

```
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr.active = false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr.active = false
```

Remove the old monitors.xml:

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Then setup the montiors with `sudo nividia-settings`. After that `apply` settings and save Xorg.conf to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Reboot, and it should work.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot see xrandr anymore in ubuntu18.04, can it be harcoded now?

Comment: there is no xrandr plugin any more setting that to false has no effect. And there is a new bug, monitors.xml is also ignored. You have to use command line tools to setup in .xinitrc

Answer (score 2):

Add `nvidia-settings --load-config-only` (see [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/alt-nvidia-current-settings.1.html)) to your startup programs, that should apply your settings each time you login.

What's happening here is that `nvidia-settings` correctly saves your settings to `~/.nvidia-settings.rc`, but can't reapply them after a restart unless run. 
Since you probably don't want to see its window every time you login, the `--load-config-only` switch tells it to load the existing config, apply it and exit.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it doesn't help. With Ubuntu 13.10 nvidia-settings -l get's automatically written to the Session Manager.
Also rerunning nvidia-settings shows me a fresh config, where all my settings have been resettet.

Comment: I think this is supposed to be the correct answer but as described it is getting overwritten on each boot on Ubuntu 22.04 as well

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with following steps.

```
mv ~/.config/monitors.xml ~/.config/monitors.xml.bak
```

That monitors.xml overrides xorg.conf every time reboot.

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

then set you want, save the file to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf`

That's it. This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is not going to work ... gnome will use default monitor setting and ignore your xorg.conf completely

Answer (score 1):

It could be that lightdm is overriding you setting. See this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/424533/248874).

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem too for years. I have PopOs 22.04, but have found a solution by creating a script.

nvidia-settings can be used on the command line to set all settings you see in the nvidia gui, but first, you need to know which attribute to set.

### The Task

In my case, I wanted to:

a) configure the locations and orientations of 4 displays
b) set one as the main display.

The steps to have these set at startup are:

1. capture the current configuration from the xorg.conf file
2. write a script that writes the orientation/location/main monitor settings via nvidia-settings command line option
3. run the script at startup

## Let's begin:

### 1) Capture the current configuration

Open the nvidia GUI through your OS, or via the command-line by typing: nvidia-settings.

Next, click "X Servier Display Configuration" set the orientation and location of each display, and the main display.

### 2) Grab the X Configuration settings

A popup appears, click "Show Preview"
[image]

Copy the preview text into an editor.

### 3) Find the options you want to save

The two options I was interested in are below:
[image]

a) nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder

b) metamodes

### 4) Find out what the attribute names are

We need to find the attribute names for the above settings so we can feed them to nvidia-settings via the command line

type

```
nvidia-settings --query all > attributes.txt
```

This will show all the possible attributes we can set,

After reading the attributes.txt, it looks like the attribute I need for order, and locations/orientations are

```
XineramaInfoOrder
CurrentMetaMode
```

### 5) Write the Script:

So I created a script using the above attributes and the values from the xorg preview:

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
sudo nano nvidiaStartup.sh
```

Now paste in the command:

```
nvidia-settings --assign <attributeName>="<your setting from xorg.conf"
```

example:

```
#!/bin/bash
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+1050, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+1080, DP-3: nvidia-auto-select +4480+1080 {rotation=right}"
nvidia-settings --assign XineramaInfoOrder="DP-1"
```

### 6) Set startup applications

Next, set the permissions of the script

```
sudo chmod u+x ~/bin/nvidiaStartup.sh
```

To access start startup settings:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

[image]

gnome-session-properties

press add
[image]

Now it will start up each time you load your OS.

To test it simply type

```
sh nvidiaStartup.sh
```

Hope this helps!