# NVIDIA Multi-monitor configuration lost after rebooting

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors of the same model plugged in an NVIDIA quadro k2200, and running Ubuntu 14.04 (using gnome shell) with the NVIDIA proprietary driver, version 375.66.

When I try to change the settings of one particular display (e.g. its rotation), these changes are lost after a reboot, and the displays are back to the default configuration.

If I use the option "Save to X configuration file", then I am unable to login after rebooting my machine (looks like the x server is crashing right after I login). If I manually try to start the x server via xinit, I get the following error:

```
Fatal server error:
[    43.484] (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
```

I have also tried to save the configuration in the system display settings after applying them with the nvidia settings program (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376922/nvidia-settings-lost-after-reboot)), but had no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?